# Symfony2 custom doctrine request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm still having a problem which let me stop on working because I don't get it solved.

I have 2 tables , Task and TaskDone. 
In Task there is stored the ID of the Task ( ID ) and the User, which the Task is assigned to ( User )

In my TaskDone Table I have the ID  of the TaskDone ( ID ) , the ID of the Task which is marked as "done" (Task_ID) and the User which the task marked as done is assigned to ( User_ID )

In my Controller I get All tasks assigned to a specific user by following code ( The request, which task is assigned to a user is done in the TWIG template by a simple IF-Request ) but I also have the chance to get the User ID in my controller ( the ID is in the URL )

```
$all_tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $id));
```

Now I only want to get all Tasks where task.ID and task.User exists in table TaskDone, so when an entry is done in TaskDone with ID = 1 | User_ID = 20 | Task_ID = 3 and I'm gettin all done tasks from the User with ID 20 I only get the Task with ID 3.

So I'm looking for something like this ( I know this piece of code is wrong )

```
    $done_tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $id) IF task.id AND task.user EXISTS in taskDone);
```

I would be so happy if someone can give me a hint, help or code how to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance,

kind regards

Marvin

Answer (score 1):

You should [describe the associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)([more info](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html)) between your entities, and perform a join(using the [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) or [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)) between the `task` and `taskDone` entities.

[MySQL docs on JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
[And a tutorial](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine2-orm-tutorial/#50)

Comment: Thank you for your links! Isn't it possible without OnetoMany, ManytoOne or ManytoMany ? Do I have to make a association between the task entite and the taskDone entite? Is there no other way? I ask, because I tried in the past with make associations but never get the code running...

Comment: You can first select all the task ids that are in `taskDone` and add a condition that the task id is among them.

Comment: Sorry...maybe I cant think logical enough for this task. But when I first take all Task ID's from the TaskDone Table which are associated with the current user, I have an array of all task ID. And then? How am I able to work with this? In normal PHP / SQL I would do it like this: SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks_done WHERE tasks_done.user_id = $userid AND tasks_done.task_id = tasks.id) = 1 AND tasks.user = $userid

Comment: You can select all the tasks that have their id [in](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) the `tasks_done` table.

Comment: Yes I know, my SQL in the comment above does so. But how to do in Doctrine / Symfony?

Comment: You can search the repositories with more than `findBy`. [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I still don't understand how to built this WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks_done WHERE tasks_done.user_id = $userid With the Doctrine...I read the docu but dont know how to do it. sorry :(